# ID Generator for Hibernate with Oracle (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to annotate ID generators in Hibernate for an Oracle DB,
I've tried this so far:

```
a) @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

says id cannot be null when I try to persist the table

```
b) @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

says Oracle doesn't support sequences (or something like that)

```
c) @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

says id cannot be null when I try to persist the table.

How should I annotate ID generators in Hibernate for an Oracle DB?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! There are multiple ways to format your questions so that they're more readable, and readable questions often get more attention and more answers. I've gone ahead and edited your post to make it more readable, once it makes it through the review process.

Answer (score 0):

You can add generation strategy as Sequence and add sequence generator to your entity:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "GEN_TABLE_NAME", sequenceName = "SEQ_TABLE_NAME")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "GEN_TABLE_NAME")
private Long id;
```

If you are not using `hbm2dll.auto` settings, you need to create sequence in your oracle database and specify it's name to "`sequenceName`" property.